# Having issues setting multiple params.require

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using a password_reset form which is being used by both a 'user' and 'admin' model. I understand that you can only pass one thing through the params.require function. It works up until the update function because I have set 'user_params' to the following:

```
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
  end
```

This is called via the update by the following code:

```
def update
  @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token(params[:id]) || Admin.find_by_password_reset_token(params[:id])
  if @user.password_reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
    redirect_to new_password_reset_path, :alert => "The Password reset has expired."
    elsif @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Your Password has been reset! You can now login."
      else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

I've tried various ways, but can't get the update to check for an admin user as well. Within the password reset controller, the @user is set by checking if a user is present or if an admin is. Example below.

```
user = User.find_by_email(params[:email]) || Admin.find_by_email(params[:email])
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by can't get update to check for admin user?

Comment: did you encounter any problem using the code above ( in the first code snippet )?

Comment: Hi, I had no problems using the standard user_params and when using :admin in place of :user, it also works.